# Angular UI-Router verify onEnter in test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, angular-ui-router

I am in the middle of writing some tests for my application (AngularJS). 
As we speak I encountered a problem with verifying if **onEnter** property of my state was called correctly.

Let me share some code with You

```
describe('Midway :: routesTest', function () {

        var $state,
            $rootScope,
            $injector,
            navigationService;

        beforeEach(function () {
            module('springatom', function ($provide) {
                $provide.value('navigationService', navigationService = {});
            });
            states.configure();

            inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$state_, _$injector_, $templateCache) {
                $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
                $state = _$state_;
                $injector = _$injector_;

                // We need add the template entry into the templateCache if we ever
                // specify a templateUrl
                $templateCache.put('/static/sa/views/home/home.html', '');
                $templateCache.put('/static/sa/tpls/grid.html', '');
            });


            navigationService.getNavigationModel = jasmine.createSpy('getNavigationModel').and.returnValue([]);
            navigationService.setNavigatorModel = jasmine.createSpy('setNavigatorModel').and.callFake(function (arg) {
            });
        });

        it("should have a working home route", inject(function () {
            var homeState = $state.get('home');

            expect(homeState).toBeDefined();
            expect($state.href(homeState)).toEqual('#/sa');

            $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                $state.go(homeState);
            });

            var current = $state.current;

            expect($injector.invoke(current.resolve.actionModel)).toEqual([]);
            expect($injector.invoke(current.onEnter)).toHaveBeenCalled();
        }));

 });
```

The failing assertion is the last one I am trying to verify therefore mentioned **onEnter**.
Error is:

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: actionModelProvider <- actionModel
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.8/$injector/unpr?p0=actionModelProvider%20%3C-%20actionModel

As it is expected Angular tries to resolve **actionModel** which is the property from the **resolve**.

I dont know what I might be doing wrong here, so any help will be gladly welcomed.

I am attaching the state configuration as well:

```
define(
    [
        'views/home/homeController',
        'views/home/recentlyUpdatedController',
        // angular deps
        'services/navigation'
    ],
    function homeState(homeController, recentlyUpdatedController) {
        return {
            name      : 'home',
            definition: {
                url        : '/sa',
                templateUrl: '/static/sa/views/home/home.html',
                resolve    : {
                    actionModel: function (navigationService) {
                        return navigationService.getNavigationModel('main.navigation')
                    }
                },
                onEnter    : function (actionModel, navigationService) {
                    navigationService.setNavigatorModel('main.navigation');
                },
                views      : {
                    '': {
                        controller : recentlyUpdatedController,
                        templateUrl: '/static/sa/tpls/grid.html'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. It seems you can't provide mocks for the injector handling onEnter. Did you resolve this somehow?